# Find an unique record in an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having a data in the following manner

```
{ _id:1, Student:"A", Subject:"Language", AddressStates:[{state:"NY"}] }, 
{ _id:2, Student:"A", Subject:"Math",AddressStates:[{state:"CA"},{state:"FL"}]}, 
{ _id:3, Student:"B", Subject:"Science", AddressStates:[{state:"CA"}] }, 
{ _id:4, Student:"A", Subject:"Arts" }, 
{ _id:5, Student:"C", Subject:"Biology" AddressStates:[{state:"NY"}]}, 
{ _id:6, Student:"B", Subject:"History" AddressStates:[{state:"NY"}]}
```

Need help in creating mongo query to fetch the records of students who are having state other than "CA". The output im expecting is only "student C" record, not student A and B as they have state "CA" in there records.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Student",
      doc: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "doc.AddressStates.state": {
        $ne: "CA"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/iwoXeiSs_pv

Comment: I am trying to find the students who are having there state other than "CA"..so only student like that is student C because  the state assigned to him is "NY"

Comment: Ok, just wait . . .

Comment: check new answer

Comment: This will give student A , student B and student C as a output, as student A has multiple records with "CA" in one and non-CA in another...But i need only student C as he is having only non-CA state

Comment: {$ne:"CA"} will only give you the result who have no 'CA', there are 4 doc who have no 'CA', But if you want Only Student:"C" document you will have to mention other distinct feature beside no 'CA.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/CmP93fN02FK check this,

Comment: thing you can do that is just adding subject name, other answer only C is not possible. Just use your head. https://mongoplayground.net/p/-eg-FoWPVd1 . check the link first.

Comment: Note: you asked ' trying to find the students who are having there state other than "CA"....only student like that is student C because the state assigned to him is "NY" '. But _d 6,5,1  also do not have CA

Comment: _id :1 is student A, he has "CA" in _id:2. same way _id:5 is student B he also has "CA" in  _id:3.

Comment: I understand now, wait, I am giving you the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Model.find({
  "AddressStates.state": "NY"
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/vk-pdOuwtvt

check link and click on, left upper side on run you will get result. You will get 2 data Student A and C

Comment: i need the Student C record only, i am looking to find the student who has the state only "NY"

Comment: then you have to run 2 conditon. 

Model.find({
  'Subject':"Biology",
  "AddressStates.state": "NY"
})

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Np2VmiUtA93 Check link

Comment: you are asking to put all the fields of the record, whats the use of query then, this is not feasible, i have 150+ fields in production...